# How to set formatting for entire row or column in xlsxwriter Python?

Tags: python, export-to-excel, xlsxwriter

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('demo1.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
format = workbook.add_format({ 'bg_color': '#5081BB','font_color': '#FFFFFF','font_size': 12,'text_wrap':'true'})
textWrap = workbook.add_format({'text_wrap':'true'})
col = 0
row = 0
for i in data["tabledata"]:
    for j in i:
        worksheet.write(row, col, j,textWrap)
        col = col+1
    row = row+1
    col = 0
worksheet.set_row(0, 20, format)
worksheet.set_row(1, 20, format)
workbook.close()
```

this doesn't properly work, then what is the use of `set_row` and `set_column`?
How to apply the format for specific row/column? I also need to apply
date format for date columns.

```
worksheet.set_column(7, none, Dateformat)
```

Answer (score 4):

Formatting works in XlsxWriter like in Excel: a cell format overrides a row format which in turn overrides a column format.

So if you want a cell to have a format plus the same formatting as the row or column you will have to define a format object that contains all the formats that you want.

Comment: I use "worksheet.set_row(0, 20, format)" it not works. this is the way to set format for entire row? normally i used to format for each cells instead of every cells how to add format for entire row?

Comment: From the code it looks like the `set_row()` format is being overwritten by individual calls to `write()` and as I said above in Excel the cell format takes precedence over the row format. If you want a format that combines a row and cell format then you need to create a new format that has the properties of both.

Comment: What does "like in Excel" mean, excatly? In Excel I can format column B as % and row 2 as bold; cell B2 will then be bold AND in %. If I try the same with xlsxwriter, cell B2 will  be bold, but not %, and all the other cells in the B column will be %. Is there any way to obtain the same result as in Excel?

Comment: In the case you describe Excel creates a third format that is a combination of the row and column format and applies it to the cell. The user can do the same in XlsxWriter. However, it doesn't happen automatically.

Answer (score 2):

#### My Code:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('demo1.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
format = workbook.add_format({ 'bg_color': '#5081BB','font_color': 
'#FFFFFF','font_size': 12,'text_wrap':'true'})
textWrap = workbook.add_format({'text_wrap':'true'})

worksheet.set_column('B:B', 18, format)       //format formatting apply to entire B column
worksheet.set_column('C:C', None, textWrap)   //textWrap formatting apply to entire C column
```

Comment: If i need to apply format to specific number of rows in a column , for e.g. from A5:A100 , then how to achieve this

Answer (score 2):

To expand on jmcnamara's answer, it's not enough to create a deep copy of the format and then modify it.

```py
import xlsxwriter
import copy

wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
default = wb.add_format({'bg_color': 'yellow'})

ws = wb.add_worksheet()
ws.set_row(0, None, default)

ws.write_string(0, 0, 'default format')

fmt = copy.deepcopy(default)
fmt.set_bold()
ws.write_string(0, 1, 'bolded and yellow', fmt)

wb.close()
```

The code above produces the following:

[image: Doesn't work]

It appears that you must use the `Workbook.add_format` method method to create a new format. Replacing

```py
fmt = copy.deepcopy(default)
fmt.set_bold()
```

with

```py
fmt = wb.add_format({'bg_color': 'yellow', 'bold': True})
```

does work:

[image: Does work]

Answer (score 0):

wrt Seema's question I have achieved this using (un)conditional_formatting, which accepts a cell range as argument, and no matter what value is in the cell, it will always apply number_format and override column and row formats:

```
``worksheet0.conditional_format('J3:V22', {
    'type': 'cell',
    'criteria': '<',
    'value': 0, 'format': number_format
        }
    )

worksheet0.conditional_format('J3:V22', {
    'type': 'cell',
    'criteria': '>=',
    'value': 0, 'format': number_format
    }
)``
```